# adding: action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" to android manifest crashes the App

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to create an app that will be the default SMS app
I have followed several guids telling to add this block to the main activity:

> 

```
<intent-filter>             
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                 <data android:scheme="sms" />
                 <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                 <data android:scheme="mms" />
                 <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
             </intent-filter>
```

This worked great (was just part of the change) and when i debug the App from android studio, all goes well (meaning running the code on my phone but using Android studio)

But, after generating a release App (apk) and installing it on a device i get this error upon opening of the App

```
2019-04-04 00:36:35.708 8404-8404/? E/GlobalPackageInstaller: launchApp error:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1581)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4526)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4484)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4845)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4813)
        at com.miui.global.packageinstaller.GlobalPackageInstallerActivity.launchApp(GlobalPackageInstallerActivity.java:306)
        at com.miui.global.packageinstaller.GlobalPackageInstallerActivity.onClick(GlobalPackageInstallerActivity.java:280)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6266)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24730)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:793)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

if i remove these 4 lines:

```
<data android:scheme="sms" />
<data android:scheme="smsto" />
<data android:scheme="mms" />
<data android:scheme="mmsto" />
```

The App does not crash (but does not appear in the list of possible SMS default apps)

Answer (score 0):

if you minify on your release variant it could be that some things are being removed that are needed by your app.  Look at your gradle file.  Specifically at your dependancies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
 layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 
'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

There are usually lines to add to the proguard file depending on what libraries you use.

Comment: minify is off, any other ideas?

Comment: try removing just the mms lines

Answer (score 0):

after breaking the "intent-filter" into two separate parts the problem was solved

Now the activity looks like this:

```
<activity
       android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
       android:exported="true"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:label="@string/app_title">
         <intent-filter>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto"/>
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

I am not sure why it solved it